# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Tags: php

подскажите как сделать вывод, если есть в базе то вывести, если нет то вывести своё -

У меня есть в базе строка banner , в нём храниться url картинки, вот если нет картинки нужно вывести заглушку. 
Я пытался так но не получаеться -\

```
 echo '<div class="prew-banner"><img src="'. if($banner){ $banner } else { '/stle/img/banner-tracker.png' } .'"></div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo '<div class="prew-banner"><img src="'. ($banner?$banner:'/stle/img/banner-tracker.png').'"></div>';
```

**Обновлено:** в случае работы с базой, когда не уверены в переменной:

```
 echo '<div class="prew-banner"><img src="'. (isset($banner) && !empty($banner)?$banner:'/stle/img/banner-tracker.png').'"></div>';
```

Comment: даже если есть в базе значение всё равно выводит , заглушку

Comment: проверьте что у вас находится в переменной $banner перед этой строкой вывода. скорей всего она пустая, либо не определена.

Comment: Да спасибо была определена выда - $banner = $row['banner'] , но почему то вызывало ошибку. 
Заменил в вашем коде $banner на $row['banner'] и всё заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
 echo '<div class="prew-banner"><img src="'; 
if($banner){ echo $banner } else { echo ('/stle/img/banner-tracker.png') };
echo ('"></div>');
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in W:\html\site\www\index.php on line 78

Comment: угу ";" нужна после echo $banner и после  echo ('/stle/img/banner-tracker.png') а после "}" убрать

Comment: Опечатка...

Comment: > if($banner){ echo $banner } else { echo ('/stle/img/banner-tracker.png') };

@Asen, ты че?


if($banner){
  echo $banner;
} else {
  echo ('/stle/img/banner-tracker.png');
}